# Inconsistent results for ANCOVA with interaction term in R

Tags: r, ancova

I need to run a Type III ANCOVA with an interaction term between a categorical and numeric variable in R. I have found three different sets of sample code to do this, and they yield identical results when I run ANCOVA without an interaction, but when I add the interaction the results diverge.

Below is some sample code for the three approaches I am comparing. First, I will show models without interactions, which yield identical results, and then I will add the interaction term, getting inconsistent results.

```
# Preparing data 
library(MASS)
data(mtcars)
data <- mtcars
data$vs <- as.factor (data$vs)
```

#### Models without interactions

Model 1 is based on https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/ancova-in-r/#computation-1

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
aov1 <- data %>% 
  anova_test(mpg ~ vs + cyl)
> get_anova_table(aov1)

ANOVA Table (type II tests)

  Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1     vs   1  29  0.226 6.38e-01       0.008
2    cyl   1  29 30.669 5.70e-06     * 0.514
```

Model 2 is based on https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/how-to-perform-ancova-in-r/

```
library(car)
aov2 <- aov (mpg ~ vs + cyl, data = data)
> Anova (aov2, type ="III")

Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: mpg
            Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 928.17  1 87.9765 2.765e-10 ***
vs            2.38  1  0.2255    0.6384    
cyl         323.56  1 30.6691 5.695e-06 ***
Residuals   305.96 29                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Model 3 is based on https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/10/analysis-of-covariance-ancova-using-r/

```
library(rstatix)
aov3 <- anova_test(data = data, formula = mpg ~ vs + cyl, type = 3, detailed = TRUE) 
> aov3

ANOVA Table (type III tests)

       Effect      SSn     SSd DFn DFd       F        p p<.05   ges
1 (Intercept) 1397.137 305.955   1  29 132.428 2.49e-12     * 0.820
2          vs    2.379 305.955   1  29   0.226 6.38e-01       0.008
3         cyl  323.564 305.955   1  29  30.669 5.70e-06     * 0.514
```

No concerns for now. All the F scores are consistent across the three models.

When I add an interaction between vs and cyl, however, the results diverge.

#### Models with interactions

Model 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
aov1_int <- data %>% 
  anova_test(mpg ~ vs * cyl)
> get_anova_table(aov1_int)

ANOVA Table (type II tests)

  Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1     vs   1  28  0.224 6.40e-01       0.008
2    cyl   1  28 30.482 6.69e-06     * 0.521
3 vs:cyl   1  28  0.823 3.72e-01       0.029
```

Model 2:

```
library(car)
aov2_int <- aov (mpg ~ vs * cyl, data = data)
> Anova (aov2_int, type ="III")

Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: mpg
            Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 540.09  1 50.8803 9.219e-08 ***
vs            5.68  1  0.5351 0.4705467    
cyl         167.06  1 15.7381 0.0004589 ***
vs:cyl        8.74  1  0.8233 0.3719539    
Residuals   297.22 28                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Model 3:

```
library(rstatix)
aov3_int <- anova_test(data = data, formula = mpg ~ vs * cyl, type = 3, detailed = TRUE) 
> aov3_int

ANOVA Table (type III tests)

       Effect      SSn     SSd DFn DFd       F        p p<.05   ges
1 (Intercept) 1405.720 297.216   1  28 132.430 3.98e-12     * 0.825
2          vs    5.680 297.216   1  28   0.535 4.71e-01       0.019
3         cyl  322.975 297.216   1  28  30.427 6.78e-06     * 0.521
4      vs:cyl    8.739 297.216   1  28   0.823 3.72e-01       0.029
```

#### Summary of results

- When comparing Model 1 and 2, the F scores are the same for the interaction term but they differ for `vs` and `cyl`.
- When comparing Model 2 and Model 3, the F scores are the same for `vs` and the interaction term, but they differ for `cyl`.
- When comparing Model 1 and Model 3, the F scores are the same for `cyl` and the interaction term, but they differ for `vs`.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me make sense of these inconsistent results and suggest which results I should trust and report.

Many thanks everyone for your attention and support!

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741417/caranova-in-r-gives-different-p-values-for-typeii-vs-typeiii-even-though-i-hav)

Comment: @Limey's link gives a likely explanation.  But more generally, you need to decide (based on your understanding of the problem you are studying) what tests you want to do.  That comes first; then figure out how to ask R to do those tests.

Comment: @user2554330--thank you for your comment. I want to test whether there is an interaction between the two independent variables in the model, one of which is categorical, the other numeric. It was my understanding that the three sample codes I reported would yield the same test, hence my puzzlement.

Comment: To clarify: I want to run a Type 3 ANCOVA

Comment: Many statisticians would consider a Type III ANCOVA that includes interations to be not sensible, for the reasons given in my answer for which I provided a link above.  And, in support of @user2554330, "I want to run a type 3 ANCOVA" is not the the question to which they refer.  More fundamentally, *what is your question of scientific interest?*

Comment: Thank you @Limey. I ran an experiment with a treatment that has two levels and a numeric DV. I would like to see whether the effects of the treatment on the DV are moderated by a numeric variable I measured before administering the treatments. What statistical approach would be more sensible than Type III ANCOVA in your opinion?

Comment: Each F value in the output corresponds to a different test.  From your comment, you should only be interested in the interaction test. Those seem to agree between the 3 methods.

Comment: @user2554330--you are right about that. I was concerned that I was getting different results for the other coefficients given that the sample code I was using was supposedly aiming to achieve the same thing. I now understand better what each test is doing. Thank you for your support.